# Explain to a layman how to choose between path analysis or multiple regression with one dependent variable

Tags: multiple-regression, path-model

Path analysis and hierarchical multiple regression are the two most common analytic methods used to examine a theoretical model. There is one dependent variable. No one has explained why they choose one method other the other.  In laymen's language please lay out the pros and cons!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "hierarchical multiple regression"? It might also help if you can provide some context (eg, your field); it is not my impression that path analysis is 1 of the "most common analytic methods".

Answer (score 2):

A multiple regression model is a special case of a path model.  There are many analyses that can be conducted via path models.  Only some of those can be fit with multiple regression models.  If a multiple regression model is a viable option, either could be used.  In that case I (and I suspect most data analysts), would use a standard multiple regression instead of a path analysis, because it would be more familiar to a wider audience.

Comment: The question seemed to be about hierarchical regression specifically and not just single-level regression, no?

Comment: Well, never mind. The title and the text don't match. Also, I could see the OP saying that multiple regression is one of the two most common analyses, but I couldn't see it for multilevel modeling.

Comment: Hmmm... those are good points, @PatrickCoulombe. We could seek to clarify the question. In particular, "hierarchical multiple regression" could mean any of several things.